# Rect x and y properties not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I'm working with svgs and I have two "rect" elements. They have four css properties of width, height, x and y. It works fine on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox the x and y properties don't show up. When I manually added them inside of the inspector there is a triangle with an exclamation point next to the x and y properties, which means it's not valid. I'm surprised by this because when I go to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) developer website I can see that these are valid properties. Since the x and y are not valid according to the Firefox browser it's causing my SVG to not render. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What is the workaround?

```
<button
   class="button button--plusButton"
   data-ng-click="plus.toggleState()"
   data-ng-class="{'is-checked':plus.state}">
   <svg viewBox="-7 9 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
      <rect class="plusButton-topBar"/>
      <rect class="plusButton-bottomBar"/>
   </svg>
</button>

.plusButton-topBar {
   x: 4px;
   y: 16.5px;
   width: 2px;
   height: 9px;
}

.plusButton-bottomBar {
   x: 0.5px;
   y: 20px;
   width: 9px;
   height: 2px;
}

.plusButton-topBar, .plusButton-bottomBar {
   fill: #656c75;
   -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   transition: all 0.218s ease;
}
```

Comment: You're misreading the MDN documentation. They are attributes, not CSS properties. SVG 2 proposes that they become properties but that specification is not finished and Firefox has not implemented that part of it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

1. X and Y are not valid css properties.

   - Move them to inline attributes.
2. Your SVG element needs dimensions.

   - Add height and width.

```css
button svg { /*add dimensions*/
  height: 20px; 
  width: 20px;
}
.plusButton-topBar {
 /*x: 4px;
   y: 16.5px;  Move these */
   width: 2px;
   height: 9px;
}

.plusButton-bottomBar {
 /*x: 0.5px;
   y: 20px;  and these*/
   width: 9px;
   height: 2px;
}

.plusButton-topBar, .plusButton-bottomBar {
   fill: #656c75;
   -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   transition: all 0.218s ease;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button--plusButton" data-ng-click="plus.toggleState()" data-ng-class="{'is-checked':plus.state}">
  <svg viewBox="-7 9 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="4" y="16.5" width="2" height="9" class="plusButton-topBar" />
    <rect x="0.5" y="20" width="9" height="2" class="plusButton-bottomBar" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

---

Just a thought...

You could use text rather than svg.

```css
button{
  color:#656c75;
  font: 1.5em "arial";
  }
```

```html
<button
   class="button button--plusButton"
   data-ng-click="plus.toggleState()"
   data-ng-class="{'is-checked':plus.state}">
 +
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a two guesses:

- First, I think x and y aren't CSS properties but HTML attributes, so
  you should include them inline in HTML tags.
- Second, your CSS rules aren't wrapped by  tag (I guess it's
  just because you pasted two different parts of file here but just
  making sure)

Answer (score 1):

for modifying the x and y for a svg element via CSS, you can use

```
transform: translate(x,y) //to modify x and y axis 
transform: translateX(x)  //to modify only x axis
transform: translateY(y)  //to modify only y axis
```